# GMount and GVolume

Tags: linux, volume, mount, gio

I am new to `GIO` and I am totally confused between `GMount` and `GVolume`. The `GIO` [reference](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.25/) says that `GMount` is a "mounted" filesystem that you can access while `GVolume` represents user-visible objects that can be mounted. I have a few questions about these two types.

1. Is a mounted `GVolume` object equivalent to a `GMount` object?
2. A mounted `GVolume` object is always associated with a `GMount` object. What is the relationship between them?
3. A `GMount` object may or may not be associated with a `GVolume` object. When is it not associated with the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

1. No.
2. Yes, 1-1 relationship by the way.
3. Virtual devices such as fpt:// etc. have only a Gmount without a GVolume.